# PHP - Create a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to create this array from some existed arrays in PHP

```
Array(
[in-door] => Array
    (
        [tv] => Array
            (
                [views] => 123
                [likes] => 234
                [comments] => 345
                [shares] => 456
            )

        [sofa] => Array
            (
                [views] => 567
                [likes] => 789
                [comments] => 890
                [shares] => 901
            )
    ),
[out-door] => Array
        (
        [chair] => Array
                (
                    [views] => 109
                    [likes] => 98
                    [comments] => 987
                    [shares] => 876
                )

        [bench] => Array
            (
                [views] => 765
                [likes] => 654
                [comments] => 543
                [shares] => 432
            )

    )

)
```

What I have tried

```
$list_categories = array("in-door");
$list_items = array(array("tv", "sofa"));
$list_items_info = array(array(array(
         "views" => 123,
         "likes" => 234,
         "comments" => 345,
         "shares" => 456
          ),
    array(
         "views" => 123,
         "likes" => 234,
         "comments" => 345,
         "shares" => 456
         )
            ));
        print_r(array_combine($list_categories, array_combine($list_items, $list_items_info)));
```

didnot bring me my expectation.

Beside that, what is the most effective way to get views/likes of an item. Should I use array or json object?

Comment: Maybe [this answer could help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116640/fill-a-multi-dimensional-array-from-an-array-of-keys-and-a-single-value/22117217#22117217).

Comment: Was this question solved? If so consider accepting an answer by clicking on the hollow check mark next to it.

Comment: Thanks both CodeAngry and Amal for helping me, especial CodeAngry (your solution is 100% match with what I need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$list_categories = array("in-door");
$list_items = array("tv", "sofa");
$list_items_info = array(
    "views" => 123,
    "likes" => 234,
    "comments" => 345,
    "shares" => 456
);

$array = array();

foreach ($list_categories as $cat) {
    foreach ($list_items as $item) {
        foreach ($list_items_info as $itemname => $iteminfo) {
            $array[$cat][$item][$itemname] = $iteminfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [in-door] => Array
        (
            [tv] => Array
                (
                    [views] => 123
                    [likes] => 234
                    [comments] => 345
                    [shares] => 456
                )

            [sofa] => Array
                (
                    [views] => 123
                    [likes] => 234
                    [comments] => 345
                    [shares] => 456
                )

        )

)
```

### [**Online demo**](https://eval.in/107874)

Comment: Thanks for helping me, this solution solves my question. However, I need to move $list_items_info inside the 1st foreach with a get_item_list_info function.